# GCMRegistrar getRegistrationId return empty ID

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android GCM : GCMRegistrar gives empty registration ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341305/android-gcm-gcmregistrar-gives-empty-registration-id)

I have followed [Writing the Server-side Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#server-app) to implement GCM in my application, but

```
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

return empy. All the time.

I put all permissions properly.

There's the code :

```
    public void registerPush(){

  GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
  GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
  final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
  REG_ID = regId;
  if (regId.equals("")) {
   GCMRegistrar.register(this, this.getString(R.string.SENDER_ID));
  } else {
   if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
    // Skips registration.
   } else {
    // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
    // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
    // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
    final Context context = this;
    mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      boolean registered = forceRegister(context, regId);
      // At this point all attempts to register with the app
      // server failed, so we need to unregister the device
      // from GCM - the app will try to register again when
      // it is restarted. Note that GCM will send an
      // unregistered callback upon completion, but
      // GCMIntentService.onUnregistered() will ignore it.


      if (!registered) {
       GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
      }
      return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      mRegisterTask = null;
     }

    };
    mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
   }
  }
 }
```

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application>
      <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="package.GCMIntentService" />

</application>
```

Comment: Got the same issue. Empty id every time. My log registers the following: V/GCMRegistrar(2409): Registering app com.myapp of senders 12345678912 and V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2409): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION and
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2409): GCM IntentService class: com.myapp.GCMIntentService and
V/GCMBaseIntentService(2409): Acquiring wakelock

Comment: Check the constructor of the GCMIntentService, make sure you have a constructor like `public GCMIntentService() {super(SENDER_ID);}` and in the manifest check the package: <category android:name="your_app_package" />

Comment: @nsemeniuk could it be anything else because I have my service set up properly (same as gcm demo example). My manifest is similar to above.

Comment: But you are stuck in the wakelock... i think is because GCMRegistrar doesn't find the receiver, or the receiver is not properly set. I had similar issues and they were caused by a wrong package name.

Comment: @nsemeniuk Well, for starters it prints the following in the log:  V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(1508): GCM IntentService class: com.myapp.GCMIntentService. This is wrong and should be com.myapp.gcm.GCMIntentService (note the gcm). But how do I get the Broadcast receiver to know this.

Comment: You should use  `<service android:name=".gcm.GCMIntentService" />` because you didn't put the GCMIntentService class on the main package, you put it on gcm package. I imagine you used `<category android:name="com.myapp" />` before.

Comment: @nsemeniuk Thanks for your help by the way. My service reads as `<service android:name=".gcm.GCMIntentService" />` (note the prefix .). But I will try your way (no prefix .). My category is set as you've described.

Comment: @nsemeniuk Nope! Bloody app is still looking here: 'com.myapp.GCMIntentService`. I wonder if it has to be this way...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18828/discussion-between-nsemeniuk-and-haraldo)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What fixed it for me was that the device was getting stuck in WAKE LOCK.

Long story short, the log pointed at the fact it was trying to find my service here:

> IntentService class: com.myapppackage.GCMIntentService

I wanted it to point here:

> IntentService class: com.myapppackage.gcm.GCMIntentService

So I extended the broadcasts receiver as follows:

```
package com.myapppackage.gcm;

import android.content.Context;

public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends
        com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {

        return "com.myapppackage.gcm.GCMIntentService";
    }
}
```

Then I updated my manifest to reflect the change:

```
<receiver 
    android:name="com.myapppackage.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" 
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.myapppackage" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is explained in the docs here(point 5):

> http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app
>
> This intent service will be called by the GCMBroadcastReceiver (which
>   is is provided by GCM library), as shown in the next step. It must be
>   a subclass of com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService, must
>   contain a public constructor, and should be named
>   my_app_package.GCMIntentService (unless you use a subclass of
>   GCMBroadcastReceiver that overrides the method used to name the
>   service).

What can I say, I'm a Taurus I like to organise my stuff properly!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, specially for the link to the explanation.

Comment: I am facing issue for very first time registration, key coming always blank ..but it come everytime for next registration...any idea..why it's coming blank for first time?

Comment: OMG Haraldo, Can i marry your brain? It really works fine. I was breaking my head for the past one hour. You saved me. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks sooooo much! I got the same issues and spent 3 days but cannot resolve until got your advices! It works for me now!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

before

```
GCMRegistrar.register(this, this.getString(R.string.SENDER_ID));
```

it is not registered yet the first time you run the app.

Check also that the GCMIntentService class has an empty constructor:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {       
        Log.i("GCMIntentService", "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    }
}
```

And also put `SENDER_ID` as `public static final String SENDER_ID = "YOUR_GOOGLE_PROYECT_ID";`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But in the tutorial, this is like that...

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#server-app

Comment: Are you testing on an ADV? if so check the GoogleAccount on API below 16. the logcat doesn't say anything? The tag is GCMRegistrar.

Comment: I'm testing on my phone ( on jelly bean ) and the logcat say nothing

Comment: The example gcm app works right? Can you include the manifest on the question?

Comment: I edit the post with the manifest

Comment: Is here (probleme w/ edit lol )

Answer (score 0):

Registraion id will come null at very first time when you install app. so  please make string regestraionId **static** here  and change on GCMIntentService.java

```
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    yourcallingactivity.regId = registrationId;
    CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_registered));
    ServerUtilities.register(context, registrationId);

}
```

Comment: I tried, but the result is the same